# Firebase functions - res.status is undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This is my code which I am executing:

```
exports.checkPin = functions.https.onCall(async (req, res) => {
    let roomDoc = await db.collection('Rooms').where('roomNum', "==", req.roomNum).get();
    if (roomDoc.exists) {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(roomDoc.data().pin, req.pin)) {
            res.status(200).send("authorised");
        } else {
            res.status(401).send("unauthorised");
        }
    } else {
        res.status(401).send("unauthorised");
    }
});
```

After executing the code, it throws an error saying that `res.status()` is `undefined`

Am I doing something wrong? I want to be able to send a response HTTP code, once the firebase function has finished executing, if this isn't the right way to do it?

Comment: With callable type functions, you don't have any control over the details of the HTTP protocol, which means you don't have direct control over the response code.  If you need to manage the response code, don't use a callable, and instead implement a standard HTTP trigger using onRequest instead of onCall as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)  and [HTTP Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

Doing `res.status(XXX).send("...");` shall be done in an HTTP Cloud Function and not in a Callable one.

**Also**, note that `roomDoc` returns a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html) and not a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot).

So you should adapt your function as follows (making the assumption that the query will return only one document):

```
exports.checkPin = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {  // <--- See here, we use onRequest and not onCall


    const querySnapshot = await db.collection('Rooms').where('roomNum', "==", req.roomNum).get();

    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {

       const roomDoc = querySnapshot.docs[0];

        if (bcrypt.compareSync(roomDoc.data().pin, req.pin)) {
            res.send("authorised");
        } else {
            res.status(500).send("unauthorised");
        }

    } else {

        res.status(500).send("unauthorised");

     }
```

PS: you may watch this official video on HTTPS Cloud Functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=1s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=3